# yargs parser supports a minimum Node.js version of 12

Tags: node.js

When I'am trying to run yarn encore dev, i get error "yargs parser supports a minimum Node.js version of 12.". When I check the version of node with `node -v` the output is `v10.19.0`. When I'm trying to update the version with `apt-get install -y nodejs`, the output is `nodejs is already the newest version (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1).`, so I can't update my nodejs.

Comment: Always use tools like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [volta](https://docs.volta.sh/guide/getting-started) to manage node version in development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the package provided by default sources in your distribution might not be up-to date. To install a specific version of NodeJS you can try using a Node Version Manager like `nvm` or `n` or `fnm`.

[NodeJS Offical Docs for Debian based systems](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)